# Show twitter followers in Plain Text

Tags: php, facebook, twitter

I am using the following php code to display Facebook Fans. Was hoping to do something similar for Twitter.

Any help Appreciated.

```
<?php
function fbfan() {
$pageID = 'facebookID';
$info = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/' . $pageID));
echo $info->likes;
}
?>
```

Using :

```
<p><?php fbfan(); ?> Facebook Fans</p>
```

The above works great meaning we can style to our hearts content, plus its lightweight.

Is there anything remotely similar for Twitter ? To echo number of followers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the twitter json file like you are with the facebook API

```
<?php
function twitterFollowers() {
$pageID = 'wesbos';
$info = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.twitter.com/users/' . $pageID .'.json'));
echo $info->followers_count; 
}
?>
```

Beware though that you should cache the json file as twitter limits you to something like 60/hour

Comment: This really helped but how can I get this to display like such: 35,000 with the comma inserted. <?php echo number_format(()); ?>

Answer (score 1):

Everything you need will be over at [dev.twitter.com](https://dev.twitter.com/docs). You'll be specifically interested in the [REST API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api)'s [get/users/show](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/show) method.

Answer (score 0):

This function will work, just input your username.

```
<?php

function getTwitterFollowers($screen_name) {
  $url = "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count=1&screen_name=" . $screen_name;
  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
  return $data[0]["user"]["followers_count"];
}

?>
<?php
  echo getTwitterFollowers("twitter");
?>
```

Make sure you cache the results, because you don't want to call this function a lot.